# When can I find a subsequence that converge weakly in $H(0,T, V)$ and pointwise a.e in $V$ for $t=0$ $?$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, convergence-divergence

The following problem is based on finding solution of PDE's using Galerkin approximation method.

Let $\{u_{m}\}$ be a bounded sequence of functions in $H^{1}(0,T;L^{2})$ i.e.,
$$||u_{m}||_{H^{1}(0,T;L^{2})}\le M $$
that satisfies:

$$u_{m}(0,\cdot)=\sum^{m}_{k=1}(g,w_{k})w_{k}$$

$$u_{m}'(0,\cdot)=\sum^{m}_{k=1}(h,w_{k})w_{k}$$

where $g\in H_{o}^{1},h\in L^{2}$ and $\{w_{k}\}^{\infty}_{k=1}$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^{2}$.

**Is there a subsequence $\{u_{m_{a}}\}^{\infty}_{a=1}$ such that $u_{m_{a}}$
converge weakly to an element $u\in H^{1}(0,T;L^{2})$ and $u_{m_{a}}(0,\cdot)$ converge a.e. pointwise to $g$ and $u_{m_{a}}'(0,\cdot)$ converge a.e. pointwise to $h$ ?**

The idea I was trying is to choose a subsequence such that $u_{m_{j}}$
converge weakly to an element $u\in H^{1}(0,T;L^{2})$. This is possible because of [Banach-Alaoglu Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem).

Now we know that the sequence converge strongly to $g$ and $h$ in $L^{2}$ that is 
$$u_{m_{j}}(0,\cdot)\rightarrow g $$ in $L^{2}$.
$$u_{m_{j}}'(0,\cdot)\rightarrow h $$ in $L^{2}$.

**Does this fact follows from Parseval's identity?**

Now since $$u_{m_{j}}(0,\cdot)\rightarrow g $$ we can choose a subsequence $\{u_{m_{j_{l}}}(0.\cdot)\}$ that converges a.e. to $g$.

Then choosing a subsequence of this last subsequence we can choose $\{u_{m_{j_{l_{r}}}}\}$ such that $\{u'_{m_{j_{l_{r}}}}(0.\cdot)\}$ that converges a.e. to $h$.

**Does choosing this last sequence give the desire properties?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is there a subsequence $\{u_{m_{a}}\}^{\infty}_{a=1}$ such that $u_{m_{a}}$
converge weakly to an element $u\in H^{1}(0,T;L^{2})$ and $u_{m_{a}}(0,\cdot)$ converge a.e. pointwise to $g$ and $u_{m_{a}}'(0,\cdot)$ converge a.e. pointwise to $h$?**

Yes, and your approach looks good for me.

**Does this fact follows from Parseval's identity?**

If you define *basis* as a *maximal set of linearly independent vectors*, then you can say that this fact follows from the fact that $\{w_{k}\}^{\infty}_{k=1}$ is a basis of $L^{2}$. The proof (and the precise relation between this fact and the Persavel identity) can be found in the reference below.

> [Corollary 12.8 (A. W. Knapp):](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=4ZZCAAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Basic+Real+Analysis+knapp&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiP5_r68IPKAhXCQ5AKHS5tC64Q6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=Basic%20Real%20Analysis%20knapp&f=false) If $S$ is an orthonormal set in the Hilbert space $H$, then the following are equivalent:
>
> (a) $S$ is maximal among orthonormal subsets of $H$.
>
> (b) $\displaystyle u = \sum_{v_\alpha\in S}(u,v_\alpha)v_\alpha$ for all $u$ in $H$.
>
> (c) $\displaystyle \|u\|^2 = \sum_{v_\alpha\in S}|(u,v_\alpha)|^2$ for all $u$ in $H$.
>
> (d) $\displaystyle (u,v) = \sum_{v_\alpha\in S}(u,v_\alpha)\overline{(v,v_\alpha)}$ for all $u$ and $v$ in $H$.

**Does choosing this last sequence give the desire properties?**

Yes because you can define $\{u_{m_a}\}$ as follows:
$$u_{m_1}=u_{m_{j_{l_1}}},\quad u_{m_2}=u_{m_{j_{l_2}}},\quad u_{m_3}=u_{m_{j_{l_3}}} \cdots\quad  u_{m_a}=u_{m_{j_{l_a}}}\quad\cdots$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I have edited the question a bit as I forgot some extra details. I will accept the question when these extra details are covered.

Comment: @yess I have tried to cover the extra details in my answer (but there is no big difference).

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to be sure that I was not missing something.